# Работа с WAV Python

Tags: python, файлы, аудио, wav

Имеется WAV файл в котором звуковая дорожка типа такой: секунда тишина, потом 5 секунд монотонный писк, потом 5 секунд тишина. Как узнать длительность писка и тишины в Python? Я так понял как-то через wave, но придумать как не могу. Прошу дать пример. Заранее спасибо

Comment: ну звук это волна https://habr.com/ru/post/113239/ может поможет найти писк )

Comment: А как это в программе сделать?

Comment: прочитать статью

Comment: Там нет того, как получить тишина или нет

Comment: Подсказка: тишина - это когда никакой волны нет, сигнал на одном уровне.

Comment: Если не тяжело дайте пример пожалуйства